# How to deal with blocking Tasks when using ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, multithreading, scheduled-tasks, task, blocking

I'd like to utilize some lightweight task management (e.g. ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor) for periodically doing some Tasks which might block (e.g. because of waiting to acquire a monitor/lock).
In such case the task management should detect that situation and should spawn another task/thread of the same kind which blocks.

How can this be achieved?

And as a bonus question: 
Documentation of ScheduledThreadPoolExecuter states that "If any execution of the task encounters an exception, subsequent executions are suppressed". In my case I rather would like to restart the task which failed. Is there a way to alter this behaviour?

Comment: If you have a blocking tasks, what would be achieved by spawning another task which would also blocks. The only sensible thing to do when one tasks blocks is to allow another non-blocking task to execute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first question : Use a java.util.concurrent.Lock and call tryLock() with a timeout. If the timeout expires (say, 5 seconds), then create a new task of the same kind as the current, pass it to the executor, and go back waiting for the lock, this time in a blocking way.

For the second question, I would consider enclosing the scheduled job in a big try/catch block to prevent unexpected exceptions to bubble up to the executor itself.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought of using 3rd party open source software? The Quartz scheduler (http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) is very flexible and is worth to try.